# Which Authentication Token (REST or SOAP) to use to getBooking in Sabre

Tags: rest, soap, sabre

Hi i am exploring Sabre APIs. I have successfully gotten result for hotel availability, lead price REST API token in Postman. But when I am trying to call getBooking endpoint using Sabre API it gives me an error relating authentication which is UNAUTHORIZED. The token I am using it from https://api.cert.platform.sabre.com/v2/auth/token.

Using this token I am trying to getBooking using following endpoint
https://api.cert.platform.sabre.com/v1/trip/orders/getBooking
Passing bearer token in header is giving me an error says "uthorization failed due to no access privileges"

so I am bit confused is it asking for SOAP API TOKEN or REST API TOKEN?

below is my request body JSON

POST : https://api.cert.platform.sabre.com/v1/trip/orders/getBooking

```
`{
  "confirmationId": "GLEBNY",
  "bookingSource": "SABRE",
  "givenName": "John",
  "middleName": "W",
  "surname": "Smith",
  "extraFeatures": {
    "returnFrequentRenter": false
  },
  "unmaskPaymentCardNumbers": false
}`

ERROR is

{
    "status": "NotProcessed",
    "type": "Validation",
    "errorCode": "ERR.2SG.SEC.NOT_AUTHORIZED",
    "timeStamp": "2023-10-06T13:34:23.124Z",
    "message": "Authorization failed due to no access privileges"
}
```